# About an sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem with SQL, i explain me :

I have 2 tables

> announcements_job
>
> announcements_education

Below you can see a preview of tables

**announcements_education**
[image: announcements_education]

**announcements_job**
[image: announcements_job]

I think my database structure is not very good ... but it's to late ! (forget my Datatype, it's bullshit actually), am i a bad man ?

So : How can you take last 5 records ORDER BY insert_db_date (between this two tables) ?

-> If it's not possible, do you have another solution?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: What do you mean between the two tables? Are they linked somehow?

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `SQL Server`? `MySQL`? `Oracle`? `DB2`? etc..

Comment: `(forget Datatype, it's bullshit)` O.o `How can you take last 5 records ORDER BY insert_db_date (between this two tables) ?` Create another table that will keep relationship between these two tables (assuming there's many to many relationship) then join these three tables, select top 5 records, that will be ordered by `[announcements_education].[insert_db_date]` and `[announcements_job].[insert_db_date]`.

Comment: You might want to take a look into JOIN (assuming your SQL has it)

Comment: Depending on what database you use, the solution I provided should spare you the trouble of merging both tables first.

Comment: @Jack : I haven't got relationship (just the term "announcement")

Comment: @PLB : (forget [...]), i just told my Datatype not optimized

Comment: @He Hui : It's not possible to use JOIN, because i haven't got many to many relationshop

Answer (score 1):

You would need to apply an order to your column before selecting. That is, assuming you don't already add always the most recent entry. But better be safe than sorry!

```
SELECT * FROM announcements_education ORDER BY DESC insert_db_date LIMIT 5;
```

respectively:

```
SELECT * FROM announcements_job ORDER BY DESC insert_db_date LIMIT 5;
```

You have to specify you are ordering by descending order as the default `ORDER BY` will sort by ascending order. The `LIMIT` statement will make sure you only return the first five entries. As your table is ordered from latest entry data to newest, only the most recent five are displayed.

**UPDATE:**

I slightly misread your question. If you want to get the top 5 across both tables, the code below is what you want.

```
(SELECT * FROM announcements_education ORDER BY DESC insert_db_date)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM announcements_job ORDER BY DESC insert_db_date)
LIMIT 5
```

Let me know it it works!

Comment: I paste your last SQL query, i get an error syntax : SQL error (1064) Syntax error near 'DESC insert_db_date) UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM announcements_job ORDER BY DESC' at line 1

Comment: I tested a simple UNION ALL between this two tables, i have got an other error -> You can't UNION ALL two tables which haven't got same number of columns ...

Comment: Ah yes, I see. My apologies. What you can do is refine the SELECT statements to just take the rows you need from both tables. If you can live with loosing two rows of information than that would be your best option. If not, then the only solution that is without loss of data is only retrieving the ID of the top five (by again modifying the SELECT statement to only return the ID) and then launch a second query retrieving them. Of course you need some logic to check what table they are in. Alternatively get the top 5 columns per table and compute the top 5 manually.

Comment: Finaly, i made a new table called "announcements", when a "recruiter" add a new announcement, i put datas into this new table and announcements_jobs or announcements_education, like this i have got a history. Thanks at all !

Comment: If that is what you wanted, you may want to look into only handling one table ever and generating two views according to announcement type. Anyway, glad we could help!